# Configuring Apache Load Balancer

Tags: apache, load, seam, load-balancing

I have the following code added to my httpd.conf to load balance between two Application Servers

```
<VirtualHost www.mydomainx.com:80>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ServerName www.mydomainx.com
ServerAlias mydomainx.com

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>    

ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
            # WebHead1
            BalancerMember http://www1.mydomainx.com
            # WebHead2
            BalancerMember http://www2.mydomainx.com
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from none
            Allow from all
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>
    <Location /balancer-manager>
            SetHandler balancer-manager

            # I recommend locking this one down to your
            # your office
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Location>
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

 </VirtualHost>
```

Whenever i enter the URL to a web browser www.mydomainx.com, it loads the home page , then if i enter a user name and password and click submit, it then reloads either (http://www1.mydomainx.com / http://www2.mydomainx.com) reloading the home page again and forcing me to re-enter the username and password, is there a way to prevent all this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the advice in section [stickyness](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_implementation):

> `ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On`

(not only for the `/test` directory)

Furthermore, for the JBoss application server, you need to supply `route=web1` / `route=web2` etc. in the Apache config and furthermore `jvmRoute="web1"` in the JBoss configuration of the `<Engine name="jboss.web"...` element (the location depends on the JBoss version you are using, for v4.2 it is `server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml`)

See also [this tutorial](http://robert-reiz.com/2010/09/30/loadbalancing-mit-apache2-tomcat-6-mod_proxy/)